# Convert GMSVisibleRegion to CLRegion or MKCoordinateRegion

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, clregion

I am using the GoogleMaps SDK and currently I am trying to convert a GMSVisibleRegion to a CLRegion.

GMSVisibleRegion is defined as:

```
typedef struct {
  CLLocationCoordinate2D nearLeft;
  CLLocationCoordinate2D nearRight;
  CLLocationCoordinate2D farLeft;
  CLLocationCoordinate2D farRight;
} GMSVisibleRegion;
```

What is the fastest way to do so?

Unfortunately it is difficult to understand what the developer meant with the naming "near" and "far". I think this comment can also be useful:

```
/**
 * Returns the region (four location coordinates) that is visible according to
 * the projection.
 *
 * The visible region can be non-rectangular. The result is undefined if the
 * projection includes points that do not map to anywhere on the map (e.g.,
 * camera sees outer space).
 */
 - (GMSVisibleRegion)visibleRegion;
```

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
Ok my first step was to create a MKCoordinateRegion of a GMSVisibleRegion.

I propose the following code to transform a a GMSVisibleRegion to a MKCoordinateRegion. Any objections.

```
+ (MKCoordinateRegion)regionForCenter:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)center andGMSVisibleRegion:(GMSVisibleRegion)visibleRegion
{
    CLLocationDegrees latitudeDelta = visibleRegion.farLeft.latitude - visibleRegion.nearLeft.latitude;
    CLLocationDegrees longitudeDelta = visibleRegion.farRight.longitude - visibleRegion.farLeft.longitude;
    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta);

    return MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess is that 'near' is for the corners of the view at the bottom of the screen, and 'far' is for the corners at the top of the screen. This is because if you've tilted the view, then the bottom corners are nearest to the camera, and the top corners are furthest from the camera.

One way to turn this into a `CLRegion` might be to use the camera's target as the centre, and then calculate the radius from the maximum distance to the four corners. This might not be the tightest fitting circle over the region, but since a circle can't fit the quadrilateral of the view anyway, it may be close enough.

Here's a helper function to calculate the distance in metres between two `CLLocationCoordinate` values:

```
double getDistanceMetresBetweenLocationCoordinates(
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord1, 
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord2)
{
    CLLocation* location1 = 
        [[CLLocation alloc] 
            initWithLatitude: coord1.latitude 
            longitude: coord1.longitude];
    CLLocation* location2 = 
        [[CLLocation alloc] 
            initWithLatitude: coord2.latitude 
            longitude: coord2.longitude];

    return [location1 distanceFromLocation: location2];
}
```

Then the `CLRegion` can be calculated like this:

```
GMSMapView* mapView = ...;
...
CLLocationCoordinate2D centre = mapView.camera.target;
GMSVisibleRegion* visibleRegion = mapView.projection.visibleRegion;

double nearLeftDistanceMetres = 
    getDistanceMetresBetweenLocationCoordinates(centre, visibleRegion.nearLeft);
double nearRightDistanceMetres = 
    getDistanceMetresBetweenLocationCoordinates(centre, visibleRegion.nearRight);
double farLeftDistanceMetres = 
    getDistanceMetresBetweenLocationCoordinates(centre, visibleRegion.farLeft);
double farRightDistanceMetres = 
    getDistanceMetresBetweenLocationCoordinates(centre, visibleRegion.farRight);
double radiusMetres = 
    MAX(nearLeftDistanceMetres, 
    MAX(nearRightDistanceMetres, 
    MAX(farLeftDistanceMetres, farRightDistanceMetres)));

CLRegion region = [[CLRegion alloc] 
    initCircularRegionWithCenter: centre radius: radius identifier: @"id"];
```

**UPDATE:**

Regarding your update for `MKCoordinateRegion`, your example code may not work. If the map has been rotated 90 degrees, then `farLeft` and `nearLeft` will have the same latitude, and `farRight` and `farLeft` will have the same longitude, and so your latitude and longitude deltas would be zero.

You would need to loop over all four of the `farLeft`, `farRight`, `nearLeft`, `nearRight`, calculate the min and max of the latitude and longitude of each, and then calculate the delta from that.

The Google Maps SDK for iOS includes a helper class which already does some of this for you - `GMSCoordinateBounds`. It can be initialized with a `GMSVisibleRegion`:

```
GMSMapView* mapView = ...;
....
GMSVisibleRegion visibleRegion = mapView.projection.visibleRegion;
GMSCoordinateBounds bounds = 
    [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithRegion: visibleRegion];
```

The `GMSCoordinateBounds` then has `northEast` and `southWest` properties which define the bounds. So you could calculate the deltas as follows:

```
CLLocationDegrees latitudeDelta = 
    bounds.northEast.latitude - bounds.southWest.latitude;
CLLocationDegrees longitudeDelta = 
    bounds.northEast.longitude - bounds.southWest.longitude;
```

You could also calculate the centre from the bounds, and therefore the `MKCoordinateRegion`:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D centre = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
    (bounds.southWest.latitude + bounds.northEast.latitude) / 2,
    (bounds.southWest.longitude + bounds.northEast.longitude) / 2);
MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta);
return MKCoordinateRegionMake(centre, span);
```

Comment: Yeah this makes sense! I have a sample code in front of me to evaluate your answer. And will report you soon. Hopefully there will be a better documentation in the future.

Comment: Hi @xen100, I added an update for the second half of your question about `MKCoordinateRegion`.

Comment: Just implemented your update answer. And will test it if it works as assumed.

Comment: So after testing I can say so far I cannot detect any mistake in the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Addendum for purists

If you want to be absolutely rigorous there's a correction you need to make around the international dateline. It would be a waste of effort in most apps but this problem has been causing me major grief as of late so I thought to throw it into the community hat

Building on Druce's update (afraid I can't make comments)...

```
GMSMapView* mapView = ...;
....
GMSVisibleRegion visibleRegion = mapView.projection.visibleRegion;
GMSCoordinateBounds bounds = 
    [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithRegion: visibleRegion];
```

Latitude doesn't need anything doing to it

```
CLLocationDegrees latitudeDelta = 
bounds.northEast.latitude - bounds.southWest.latitude;
```

The deal runs that a region that spans the international dateline might have a southWest corner in Japan (+140 longitude) and its northEast corner in Alaska (-150 longitude). Adding up and dividing by two gives a point around the wrong side of the globe.

The special case where northEast.longitude is less than southWest.longitude needs handling

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D centre;
CLLocationDegrees longitudeDelta;

if(bounds.northEast.longitude >= bounds.southWest.longitude) {
//Standard case
    centre = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
             (bounds.southWest.latitude + bounds.northEast.latitude) / 2,
             (bounds.southWest.longitude + bounds.northEast.longitude) / 2);
    longitudeDelta = bounds.northEast.longitude - bounds.southWest.longitude;
} else {
//Region spans the international dateline
    centre = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
             (bounds.southWest.latitude + bounds.northEast.latitude) / 2,
             (bounds.southWest.longitude + bounds.northEast.longitude + 360) / 2);
    longitudeDelta = bounds.northEast.longitude + 360 
                    - bounds.southWest.longitude;
}
MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta);
return MKCoordinateRegionMake(centre, span);
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on answer of @Saxon Druce, this is a quick extension on setting and getting `region` using MKCoordinateRegion on `GMSMapView`

```
extension GMSMapView {
    var region : MKCoordinateRegion {
        get {
            let position = self.camera
            let visibleRegion = self.projection.visibleRegion()
            let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(region: visibleRegion)
            let latitudeDelta = bounds.northEast.latitude - bounds.southWest.latitude
            let longitudeDelta = bounds.northEast.longitude - bounds.southWest.longitude
            let center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
                (bounds.southWest.latitude + bounds.northEast.latitude) / 2,
                (bounds.southWest.longitude + bounds.northEast.longitude) / 2)
            let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta)
            return MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span)
        }
        set {
            let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(newValue.center.latitude - newValue.span.latitudeDelta/2, newValue.center.longitude - newValue.span.longitudeDelta/2)
            let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(newValue.center.latitude + newValue.span.latitudeDelta/2, newValue.center.longitude + newValue.span.longitudeDelta/2)
            let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: northEast, coordinate: southWest)
            let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fitBounds(bounds, withPadding: 0)
            self.moveCamera(update)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking for boilerplate code based on all the answers and corrections provided so far, here's `region` implemented as a category on GMSMapView:

```
//
//  GMSMapViewExtensions.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@interface GMSMapView (GMSMapViewExtensions)

@end
```

and

```
//
//  GMSMapViewExtensions.m
//

#import "GMSMapViewExtensions.h"

@implementation GMSMapView (GMSMapViewExtensions)

- (MKCoordinateRegion) region {
    GMSVisibleRegion visibleRegion = self.projection.visibleRegion;
    GMSCoordinateBounds * bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithRegion: visibleRegion];

    CLLocationDegrees latitudeDelta = bounds.northEast.latitude - bounds.southWest.latitude;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D centre;
    CLLocationDegrees longitudeDelta;

    if (bounds.northEast.longitude >= bounds.southWest.longitude) {
        // Standard case
        centre = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
            (bounds.southWest.latitude + bounds.northEast.latitude) / 2,
            (bounds.southWest.longitude + bounds.northEast.longitude) / 2);
        longitudeDelta = bounds.northEast.longitude - bounds.southWest.longitude;
    } else {
        // Region spans the international dateline
        centre = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
            (bounds.southWest.latitude + bounds.northEast.latitude) / 2,
            (bounds.southWest.longitude + bounds.northEast.longitude + 360) / 2);
        longitudeDelta = bounds.northEast.longitude + 360 - bounds.southWest.longitude;
    }

    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta);
    return MKCoordinateRegionMake(centre, span);
}


- (MKMapRect)visibleMapRect {
    MKCoordinateRegion region = [self region];
    MKMapPoint a = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
        region.center.latitude + region.span.latitudeDelta / 2,
        region.center.longitude - region.span.longitudeDelta / 2));
     MKMapPoint b = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
        region.center.latitude - region.span.latitudeDelta / 2,
        region.center.longitude + region.span.longitudeDelta / 2));
     return MKMapRectMake(MIN(a.x, b.x), MIN(a.y, b.y), ABS(a.x - b.x), ABS(a.y - b.y));
}

@end
```

Usage example:

```
GMSMapView * mapView = .... // init code
MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion = mapView.region;
```